# How find/replace special character + with space regular Expression in SRC=""

Tags: regex, notepad++

Hello i'm trying with notepad ++ to find in SRC of tag  special characters **+** and replace with **space** with regular expression.

For example `src="www.miosito.it/image/la+sagra+della+porchetta.jpg"`

I want to replace each + with space with regular expression so: `src="www.miosito.it/image/la sagra della porchetta.jpg"`.

Comment: `(?:\bsrc="|\G(?!\A))[^+]*\K\+` replace with space

Answer (score 0):

As per my original comment...

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/rxiONd/1)

```
(?:\bsrc="|\G(?!\A))[^+]*\K\+
```

Alternatively, you can use `(?:\bsrc="|\G(?!\A)).*?\K\+`, but the other regex gives better performance.

Replacement:  (space)

---

### Results

#### Input

```
src="www.miosito.it/image/la+sagra+della+porchetta.jpg"
```

#### Output

```
src="www.miosito.it/image/la sagra della porchetta.jpg"
```

---

### Explanation

- `(?:\bsrc="|\G(?!\A))` Match either of the following

  - `\bsrc="`

    - `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
    - `src="` Match this literally
  - `\G(?!\A)` Assert position at the end of the previous match
- `[^+]*` Match any character except `+` any number of times. The alternative uses `.*?` which matches any character any number of times, but as few as possible
- `\K` Resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match
- `\+` Match `+` literally

Answer (score 0):

Use Notepad++ regex Find-and-Replace:

Find what:

```
(src="[^"]*)\+
```

Replace with:

```
$1
```

(NOTE: The $1 has a single space after it). Keep clicking "Replace All" until all occurrences have been replaced.